# Работа с полями типа time

Tags: php, sql, время

Здравствуйте! У меня есть в таблице два поля time_1 и time_2 в них хранится время например 17:00:00 и 02:00:00
Мне нужно вывести те строки где реальное время больше time_1 и меньше time_2. Всё бы ни чего но если сейчас к примеру 18:00:00 то второе условие не сработает так как 18 больше чем 2. И вот не могу сообразить. Добавлять дату мне не нужно. Подскажите как можно правильно условие составить?

Comment: Без учёта даты 2 часа ночи никогда не будут позже 17 часов.

Comment: Тогда вопрос в другом как хранить эти данные? Это режим работы, и у каждой записи он свой. С 10 до 20, с 9 до 13, с 11 до 1 к примеру. Т.е. по факту здесь дата не нужна.

Comment: например, начало периода и длительность

Comment: Спасибо, обмозгую)